# How to add "addThis" social integration into a lightbox (jquery prettyphoto or jquery fancybox)?

Tags: lightbox, sharing, addthis

I am having some problem with the integration of "addthis" social sharing inside a lightbox so that image can be shared from lightbox.

I tried with prettyPhoto and fancybox but there is something to do with callback functions, and I can not find a way to make it work.

I found this thread, but it doesn't provide much help: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/132264-addthis-in-a-lightbox

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was looking for something similar, I have found that calling `addthis.layers.refresh();` does the job.

You only have to make sure the function is defined before you try calling it:

```
if(addthis.layers && typeof addthis.layers.refresh === 'function'){
    addthis.layers.refresh();
}
```

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1692927-using-dashboard-configuration-tools-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly, add it before `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//always refresh on URL change
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
  addthis.layers.refresh();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at reveal.js instead of lightbox